# WPF - TabItem MouseOver not working as intended

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, ismouseover

I have an issue with the IsMouveOver trigger with a TabItem Element.

When the mouse cursor is on a TabItem, its background color changes, which is what I want => It works.
However the background color of the TabItem also changes whenever my mouse cursor is on an item inside the TabItem.

Here's the XAML related to the styling:

```
    <Style x:Key="SupTest" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border Margin="2" Name="TabBorder" CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" 
                        BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel Margin="12" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="00,0,0,0"></Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,0"></ContentPresenter>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="#FFDFDFDF" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WindowTitleColorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkRed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WindowTitleColorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And the XAML code for the windows itself:

```
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TabStripPlacement="Left"
                BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource WindowTitleColorBrush}">
        <TabItem Header="Item #1" Style="{StaticResource SupTest}">
             <Grid>
                <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            </Grid>
        <TabItem Header="Item #2" Style="{StaticResource SupTest}">
             <Grid>
                <Button Content="Button Teeest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

With this code for example, the IsMouseOver of a TabItem is triggered when the mouse cursor is on the button it contains.

How to fix this? :P

Thanks for the help =)

Comment: Have you tried `<Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="True">`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I have now :P But it didn't work, this event doesn't get triggered at all whatever I do it seems. Thanks for the suggestion though =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work because Border as container takes all events, and `MouseOver` is not exception. If you want to ignore `MouseOver` event for some part (your inner part of the item) then just put inner item on top of wider item.

You can add Grid control beneath inner part and bind `Trigger` to its `MouseOver` event.

```
    <Border Margin="2" Name="TabBorder" CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" 
BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="gridMouseOver"/>
    <StackPanel Margin="12" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="00,0,0,0"></Rectangle>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,0"></ContentPresenter>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="#FFDFDFDF" />
    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WindowTitleColorBrush}"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkRed" />
    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger SourceName="gridMouseOver" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WindowTitleColorBrush}"/>
</Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 5):

bit of an old question but this has been troubling me all day....

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

This solved it for me

ignores the mouse over for the active tab

Hope this helps any one who has this problem

Comment: Way simpler than the accepted answer, worked like a charm for me